# Bokeh: how to flush spectrogram

Tags: bokeh

I'm using [bokeh spectrogram example](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/tree/master/examples/app/spectrogram) and I need to clear image. Is there any way to add new function named `flush` to `WaterfallRendererView` class that I could call from `main.py`: `waterfall_renderer.flush()`?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As of Bokeh `0.12.4` there is not any direct way. The best way to "fake it" would be to add a property to `WaterfallRenderer` that exists solely for the purpose of triggering events in `WaterfallRendererView`.

```
class WaterfallRenderer(Model):
    flusher = Int()

    def flush(self):
        self.flusher += 1
```

Then on `WaterfallRendererView` you can set up something like:

```
@listenTo(@model, 'change:flusher', @flush)
```

in `0.12.5` there will be a new API for "fire and forget" events that will make it possible to implement things like this in a less kludgy way.

Comment: Thanks, it works, but what's bothering me - after pushing 'flush' button it takes several seconds to actually flush spectrogram. So for now I just replace figure's renderer with a new WaterfallRenderer object - it's faster.

Comment: I would say that's unexpected but it's not really possible to say more without running/debugging code. Feel free to come by the public mailing list if you are interested in that kind of iterative discussion (Stack Overflow is not good for that)